# Isotope columnWidth and Gutter options not working

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using just the default code provided by the isotope website. The plugin works, its on the page just fine. By default, without specifying a columnwidth and a gutterwidth, isotope applies a 7px margin automatically between elements. However, i want to make this margin less and trying to pass the columnwidth and gutterwidth as instructed by the documentation, i always fail. the code is:

```
$container.isotope({
     itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
     masonry : {
        columnWidth: 300, 
        gutterWidth: 2
               }
});
```

there is no live url to check it out, but you can check it out here, where all i did was create a copy of the "official" jsfiddle and just add the columnwidth and gutter width. You can see that while the box width and height is 70px, it is not working right, unless there is something i do not understand..

http://jsfiddle.net/PUhtY/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer, you will need the jQuery Gutter Width Extension.

https://gist.github.com/Huskie/2574891

Whack it outside your isotope function and you should be ready to go! I had the same issues and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you use `guuterWidth` instead of `gutter`.

change your code to something like this:

```
$container.isotope({
 itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
 masonry : {
    columnWidth: 300, 
    gutter: 2
    }
});
```